# Select first word in string with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to add a span class after the first word in a string with jQuery. I am using following code:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var test = $(this);
    test.html( test.text().replace(/(^\w+)/,'<span>$1</span>') );
});
```

This will work fine with the standard characters, but it won't work with the **non-English Characters**.

Please see the demo, it should select the whole word "Bài", but it only selects "B". How this can be fixed?

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/hez4ohpc/

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Support for Unicode in JavaScript regular expressions is currently very poor ([this will be much better in ES6](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2012/05/ecmascript-supplementary-characters/index.html#RegExp)). In such a case your best option would probably be to use a more complete regular expression solution. The best I know is the [XRegExp](http://xregexp.com/) library.

The second best option would be to try to define what *doesn't* make a word :

```
.replace(/([^\s\.,\:;!?]+)/,'<span>$1</span>')
```

but that's dangerous and you'll expose you to surprises later when you'll realize what caracter you forgot.

Comment: He can learn at mistakes ;) I think this is the best way to do this. Or use PHP where is better support for unicode...

Comment: why focus on characters? look my answer, think thats the best Option in that case

Comment: @FelixLahmer It looks like you don't understand the other answers or even why OP used `\w`, which *is* the best practice when your regex engine isn't too poor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var test = $(this);
    test.html( test.text().replace(/(^[^\s]+ )/,'<span>$1</span>') );
});
```

Comment: That `.` will match any kind of character, inclusing spaces, won't it?

Comment: Are you sure that first word is followed by space?

Comment: @Krzysiek As OP wrote in his example, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that?

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    var test = $(this);
    test.html( test.text().replace(/(^[^\s,\.\:\;\"]+)/,'<span>$1</span>') );
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is an alternative Solution to your Question, with which you have no need to escape or .replace anything.

```
$('h1').each(function() {
   var html = $(this).html();
   var word = html .substr(0, html.indexOf(" "));
   var rest = html .substr(html.indexOf(" "));
   $(this).html(rest).prepend($("<span/>").html(word).addClass("em"));
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6NyfY/109/)

***EDIT:*** As discussed in the comments, the downside of this solution is, that it **will not work**, **if** the **first word** is **not followed** by a **space**.

Comment: This assumes the first word ends with a space. And why do you propose replacing a fast concise regex by such a verbose code ?

Comment: @dystroy and how could a word not end with a space?

Comment: What's after the last word of your last comment ? Hum ?

Comment: @dystroy my solution assumes, that there is at least 1 word followed by a space,  which applies to all of the OP´s given scenarios. I´d do it like this for that particular case (special characters), before fighting around with regex.

Comment: @dystroy If it should be the case that OP has non spacy headings with a lot of ?!"§$%&/(), he can feel free to comment and I´ll rewrite my snippet for his case. But given his examples, my solution seems to be easier and more solid, than all those .replace stuff where u can forget a lot of Characters, especially if you use non-english Characters like the OP